# Enabling NAT loopback on Zyxel C3000Z Modem/Router?

Tags: networking, router, nat, loopback

I have a C3000Z router from Century Link and it does not have NAT loopback enabled by default. The option is simply not available on the Web GUI. However browser around I found a few other models of Zyxel routers where you could enable NAT loopback via the Telnet CLI. I tried those instructions of course, but no luck. 
Does anyone know how to do it on a C3000Z, or if it is even possible ?

Comment: Does Century Link let you telnet in?

Comment: Yes. I can telnet in. The commands usually found online to enable NAT loopback is the "ip" command, which does not seems to be available on my modem :(

Comment: You can always either 1. upgrade your router to one that supports Nat hairpinning. 2. Edit your host config to redirect the fqdn request to the local server IP. (Also can be accomplished with a local DNS server) Or just use the local address when your on the lan.

Comment: Well upgrading the router is kind of annoying. Until I was using an Apple Time capsule which had no issue with Nat hairepinning, but it wasn't powerful enough to route the gigabit internet connection. So I just acquired that router to replace the Time Capsule :( And regarding the host file, it's not going to work because I use a laptop in and out of the lan (don't want to have to change the host file every 5 minutes) and in addition the services that I am routing are coming from multiple source inside the LAN, so I can't just simple point the public domain name to one specific IP...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to set up a Zyxel C3000Z configuration where NAT loopback works. 
After several days of experiments, only the following worked:

1. turned on (previously unused) Asus RT-N16 router, upgraded firmware, plugged its WAN into Zyxel's LAN1 port;
2. switched Zyxel into Transparent Bridge mode;
3. called ISP (CenturyLink) and obtained PPP username and password;
4. entered the username and password in the Asus' Admin (http://192.168.1.1), then switched WAN Connection Type to PPPoE; checked that Internet is working fine;
5. enabled SSH and Telnet in Administration->System page;
6. executed command in telnet (connected to 192.168.1.1):

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
   ```
7. configured WAN->Port Forwarding for HTTP and other custom ports to allow external access to the LAN webserver and tcp-server.

After the above steps completed I'm able to browse my local webserver from outside the house, and from inside – using global IP address. Moreover, other custom TCP servers are accessible via domain name as well!

Comment: So, your solution was to use another router?